# Display directory structure to admin

Tags: php, javascript

i am developing a CMS in which i hav to show the administrator the directory structue of root folder. What im doing is getting the directory structure using php and trying to print it on the client web page using javascript `(echo"<script>javaFunc()</script>")` , now after visiting different forums, i see people are saying that its not a gud idea to call javascript from php!! is it so? if yes then wats shud be the proper way for displaying the server directory structure, at client side?

Answer (score 3):

Would be a good idea to echo back the array of directory names as a JSON array, so compile your array in PHP then json_encode() it in PHP.

```
$directories = array('file1', 'file2');
echo json_encode($directories);
```

Then get the data using AJAX at the client side and format it how you want. (jquery example)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    success: function(return_data)
    {
        // return_data has your directories
    }
});
```

Be very careful you don't allow people to trick the server into listing ie. the root folder or worse by using functions realpath() and basename() and proper validation.